# What is the correct way to write sum from 47 to 54 so it means 404?

Tags: summation

[image]

Does the above image correctly mean "This is a 404 error?"

That is, does this

$$
\sum_{i = 47}^{54}
$$

mean 404? Or should it just be this,

$$
\sum_{47}^{54}
$$

without the equals?

Comment: It should be $$\sum_{i = 47}^{54} i$$

Comment: Strictly the sum would be $8error$ - what else would the summand be?

Comment: @Mark why would it be 8?

Comment: $47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54$ - the sum covers $8$ integers $\dots$

Comment: @Darth Thanks, do add as an answer!

Comment: @Mark ahh okay, so what Darth says is correct! Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed - you just have to add the right thing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be $$\sum_{i = 47}^{54} i$$

Note that: $$\sum_{i = 47}^{54} i = (47 + 0) + (47 + 1) + \ldots + (47+7) =\\ 47·8 + (0+1+\ldots+7) =  47·8 + \frac{7·8}{2} = 404$$

As desired. This is what I think was intended but here are many more options, such as:

$$\sum_{i = 47}^{54} \frac{404}{8} = 404$$

$$\sum_{i = 47}^{54} (101-i) = 404$$

Comment: Yeah, I just found [this wolfram|alpha widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=dfaf1b7d15e572ae5a1b2fa172ce8657&title=Math%20Help%20Boards%3A%20Sum%20Calculator&theme=blue) - If you want you could edit to include it!